# What is more dangerous: A Griffin or a Hippogriff?

Tags: harry-potter

Which would be seen as more deadly in comfrontation with a witch or wizard?

Only canonical answers please.

Comment: Normally questions about which is more deadly/would win in a fight/is more dangerous, etc are considered off-topic (due to being opinion-based). In this case there's actually a reference in one of the potter books that shows which is more deadly.

Comment: there is no griffin in Harry Potter I think

Comment: except the griffin head knocker on Dumbledore's door, but that does not show if a griffin is a real creature in the Harry Potter universe

Comment: A Griffin is a real creature @user13267 it is classified as a beast with a ministry classification rating of XXXX meaning it is a threat and will kill humans but obviously buckbeak is a dangerous creature!

Comment: @Richard what is it then? Griffin or Hippogriff?

Comment: This is a bad question with a good answer. Just because it happens to have a conanical answer doesn't make it not a "Gorilla vs. Shark" question.

Comment: @legostormtrooper - Ah, but that only applies to questions from multiple universes. Since both exist in the same canon it's consisted on topic. Gorilla vs gorilla

Comment: I think this is more like a wild gorilla vs a zoo bred gorilla. Both exist so technically should be feasible to determine which is stronger than the other, but we do not have any data on one fighting the other to determine who would actually win in a fight. I think it would be akin to asking if Voldemort would have won a duel against Grindelwald.

Comment: as per as the world of harry potter hippogrifs were tamed by Hagrid but when Draco Malfoy tried to do the same with no so good attidude the creature became aggressive and attacked .as per as fantastic beasts and where to find them the griffin had a xxxx classification which means it is dangerous and it is also known as gaurds of btreasures while hippogrifs were easily tamed by even sirius black so the griffin is more dangerous altough the hippogriff is no less

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the excellent"[Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts_and_Where_to_Find_Them)" (By JK Rowling), each beast is provided with a Ministry of Magic classification offering an

> ***"at-a-glance guide to the perceived dangerousness of a creature***".

The Hippogriff is classified with three **XXXs**, indicating that a

> "Competent wizard should cope"

whereas by comparison, the Griffin is marked with four **XXXXs**, indicating that it is

> "**Dangerous** / Requires specialist knowledge / Skilled wizard may
>   handle"

---

In the Harry Potter universe, Griffins appear to be analogous to guard dogs:

> Griffins are often employed by wizards to guard treasure. Though
>   griffins are fierce, a handful of skilled wizards have been known to
>   befriend one.

Whereas the Hippogriff is more analogous to a horse which can be tamed and ridden:

> It has the head of a giant eagle and the body of a horse. It can be
>   tamed, though this should be attempted only by experts. Eye contact
>   should be maintained when approaching a Hippogriff. Bowing shows good
>   intentions. If the Hippogriff returns the greeting, it is safe to draw
>   closer.

Comment: As a sidenote, your descriptions of the functions of both follow directly from their mythological origins: the Hippogriff was first mentioned in a medieval story by Aristo, in which it was a mount. The griffin first appeared in one of the Greek travel stories as the 'gold-guarding griffins of the Scythians'.

Comment: @Charles which is more likely than not deliberate on JKR's part, great info though.

Comment: @BMWurm: Yes, I think so too. It's not an answer since the question was about her universe and not real-world mythology but I thought it was worth pointing out.